# Removing JavaScript from a link

Tags: javascript

The link's code is as follows:

```
<td class="buttonColumn">
<a href="javascript:confirmDialog('Are you sure you want go?', 'http://google.com');" class="actionButtonNew">Leave to Google</a>
</td>

<td class="buttonColumn">
<a href="javascript:confirmDialog('Are you sure you want go?', 'http://yahoo.com');" class="actionButtonNew">Leave to Yahoo</a>
</td>
```

There are multiple buttons on the page with the exact same format that need to be changed as well. I was thinking something like this:

```
var fix = document.getElementsByClassName('actionButtonNew');
for (var i=0; i<fix.length; i++) {
```

I am not sure how to finish the code. I tried this:

```
var fix = document.getElementsByClassName('actionButtonNew');
for(var i = 0; i < fix.length; i++) {
    try {
        var l = fix[i];
        var h = fix[i].parentNode.getElementsByClassName('actionButtonNew')[0].href.replace("javascript:confirmDialog('Are you sure you want to go?',", "");
        l.href = h;
    } catch(e) {}
}
```

I know it is very messy and bad. It does change the link to: 'http://google.com');

So I think I may be on the right track. Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with the links after they are changed (e.g. no link, remove all http://...)?

Comment: I want the link to direct to the website. ie: The Google link to go to http://google.com

Comment: So remove the confirmation?

Comment: Yes, remove the JavaScript conformation.

Comment: instead of replace, why don't you just do `.href = "http://google.com"` ?

Comment: I can't change the website's HTML coding...each link is to a different website, too.

Comment: no, above you're doing: `.href.replace(....`, when you can just do `.href = .....`

Comment: And each link is different. Doing .href = http://google.com would make them all go to Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea: rather than deal with messy regular expressions that are bound to break on some edge case, replace `confirmDialog` with a function that redirects without confirming:

```
window.noConfirm = function(m, url) {
    document.location.href = url;
}

var fix = document.getElementsByClassName('actionButtonNew');
for (var i = 0; i < fix.length; i++) {
    fix[i].href = fix[i].href.replace('confirmDialog', 'noConfirm');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AV4tB/

And another funny idea: change it call a function that immediately fixes the link, then trigger a click:

```
window.fixMe = function(m, url) {
    this.href = url;
}

var linksToFix = document.getElementsByClassName('actionButtonNew');
for (var i = 0; i < linksToFix.length; i++) {
    window.a = linksToFix[i];
    linksToFix[i].href = linksToFix[i].href.replace('confirmDialog(', 'fixMe.call(a, ');
    linksToFix[i].click();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AV4tB/1/

Comment: Hey, didn't think of that. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty annoying to say to users "do you really want to do that?" every time they click on a link. After all, the back button will usually bring them straight back, or the escape key will cancel navigation if they're quick.

Since A elements may not all be links (some are targets), you can get all the links in a page using the `document.links` collection, then iterate over that:

```
// Function to call
function navPrompt() {
  var text = this.textContent || this.innerText
  return confirm('Are you sure you want to go to ' + text + '?');
}

// Attach to all listeners
window.onload = function() {

  var links = document.links;
  var i = links.length;
  while (i--) {
    links[i].onclick = navPrompt;
  }
}
```

On the otherhand, if you want to remove the comfirm box and change:

```
href="javascript:confirmDialog('Are you sure you want go?', 'http://google.com');"
```

to:

```
href="http://google.com"
```

you can do:

```
window.onload = function() {

  var link, links = document.links;
  var i = links.length;
  while (i--) {
    link = links[i];
    link.href = link.href.replace(/.*(http[^\'\"]+).+/i,'$1');
  }
}
```

Which will strip out the URL and assign it to the href property.

Comment: Could you make a jsFiddle link of it? I can't get it to work :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var fix = document.getElementsByClassName('actionButtonNew');
for (var i = 0; i < fix.length; i++) {
    fix[i].href = fix[i].href.replace(/javascript:confirmDialog\(\'Are you sure you want go\?\'\, \'(http\:\/\/.*\.(.){2,3})'\);/gi,'$1');
}
```

Which uses regex to replace the confirm JS with just the links.
E.g. `"javascript:confirmDialog('Are you sure you want go?', 'http://yahoo.com');"` becomes `"http://yahoo.com"`